# Never left if condition

Tags: apex, conditional, if, cloudcraze

I've got a tricky question, my code doesn't work - suprise. 
I would like to return only a list of 'filtred' data but my code never leav a if condition. 
So when if condition return true and my script go inside if body, it never go outside. 
I can not use a break.

```
for(ccrz.cc_bean_EffectiveAccount eff :effectiveAccount ){
        System.debug('nonetraid ' + noneTradingAccountIds);
        System.debug('eff.sfid ' + eff.sfid);
            if(noneTradingAccountIds.contains(eff.sfid)){
                System.debug('nonetraid w if' + noneTradingAccountIds);
                Integer indexOf = effectiveAccount.indexOf(eff);
                System.debug('indexof' + indexOf);
                effectiveAccount.remove(indexOf);
                effectiveAccount2 = effectiveAccount;
                System.debug('effacc loop' + effectiveAccount);
  //                    break;
            }
    }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you mean that your code stuck in infinite loop by "it never go outside"? Ideas is that collection, iterated in loop should never be changed inside a loop to avoid such kind of things

Comment: I believe it is because you are iterating and modifying the same list at the same time which is causing inconsistency. You can either create a separate list to store the items to be removed and remove the elements after the `for` loop or use the Iterator methods which allow manipulation of lists while iterating over them.